# I'm looking to connect a Google VM to a website

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, csv, google-cloud-platform

I need reflection, vision and documentation on my problem.

I wrote a python script to calculate something from an API and export the result in a CSV file. Then, I use a JavaScript script to display the data from this CSV file on a building website.
I need to have the latest data available for my website, so I opened a VM instance in Google Cloud Platform (Google Compute Engine) and set a Crontab job to run automatically my python script. The calculation is now executed every day and the result is exported to the CSV file, but stored in this VM instance.

Here is my goal: How can I get my CSV file on my website? The CSV is always on the virtual machine and I do not know how to communicate with my JavaScript script to the VM. Do I have to communicate directly with the VM? Do I have to go through another step before (server, API, etc.)?

I cannot find a specific solution for my problem on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Tim! Sadly your question is too broad (or rather requires too much steps) and can not be answered specificly. Here is a basic tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial) General steps are, you mount your domain, then attach the domain to your VM, google DNS will automatically update IP of your VM to your domain once you do it, rest is backend stuff. As you say you run a cronjob, I would suggest you install nginx and make your cronjob output file to `/var/www/html/csv-data` so you can just access it via `https://yourdomain.com/csv-data`.

Comment: Where is hosted your website?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Boujour, le site n'est pas encore sortie, il est en construction. Il est donc en local sur mon PC mais a partir du moment ou j'arriverai a établir la connexion que je souhaite, il me semble que j'aurai juste les paramètres à changer une fois en production/en ligne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get my CSV file on my website?

By making your python script output the CSV into your website's root folder.

Example, if you're running apache, chances are your root folder is somewhere in `/var/www/html/...`

If the script is generated from another machine (not the one with your website), then I would host it and make the server hosting your website fetch it via cronjob.

Basically:
If your CSV is generated from the same machine as the website that will use it - simply output it to the website's folder

If your CSV is generated from another machine, make it publicly accessible and have your website's machine cronjob fetch that CSV a few minute after it's generated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a different approach than using a VM for calculating and storing your CSV.

The idea would be using a Python Cloud Function instead, that will be run by [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/schedule-run-cron-job) and Pub/Sub.

This function will generate your CSV file, that will be stored on Cloud Storage. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample) you can find an example of how to upload an object to Cloud Storage using Python.

Then, you need to give your website the ability to access that CSV file in Cloud Storage when required. As indicated by @guillaumeblaquiere, the exact way will be dependent on where your website is hosted: especially, it will constraint the auth mechanisms that you need to use to download your data. The documentation in GCP provides several [examples](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) about this matter.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) of Google Cloud provides an example of the proposed architecture.

I came across [an article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-schedule-a-serverless-google-cloud-function-to-run-periodically-249acf3a652e) that, in a certain way, describes the setup I suggested as well.

Please, consider review the costs of the different mentioned products.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and this different approach. Google Scheduler can work without a VM ? My website is not online, because it is on development. But I guess if I find a solution with a local devolpment, I will have simply to change the settings for the online version.

Comment: You are welcome @Tim.  Yes, Cloud Scheduler has nothing to do with VM, is a completely different [product](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler). basically, it gives you the ability to run scheduled jobs, let's say, it is a kind of cloud crontab service, very summarized, of course. You can use the same [APIs and client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) no matter if you are developing locally or if your application is hosted in any other place: the only thing that may, or not, change is the way you authenticate your application against Cloud Storage. Please,...

Comment: feel free to ask what you consider appropriate, I will try to help if possible.

Comment: Hi @jccampanero, after reflection, I'm looking for install a Apach server on my Google VM to deploy my website. All files, scripts and crontabs will be in the same machine, so it seems easy to connect them together.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @Tim. Yes, I agree with you, it is certainly a viable and good solution. I am glad to hear that you managed to solve your problem.